# How to save input type "color"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, colors

Im working at a profile page and want to add a 'favorite color' button.
So this is the code I used in my view:

```js
var saveChanges = function ()
{
    var jsonData = {};

    $('#user_info input').each(function () {
        var key = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
        jsonData[key] = value;
    });
```

```html
   <span class="form-label">Your favorite color:</span>
    <input id="my_color" type="color"/>`<span class="form-label">
```

So on the profile page the 'color picker' is visible.

This is the save function in my javascript. (it works for the other profile options.

```
var saveChanges = function ()
{
    var jsonData = {};

    $('#user_info input').each(function () {
        var key = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
        jsonData[key] = value;
    });
```

I can save the color I picked and if I look it up in my database (my_color) I see the hex color code I picked so that is working.
But after I save my profile and I refresh the page you still see the default (black) color and not the color I picked before saving.

Can someone help me to show the color on the profile page.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you set default input type color value as database color value? Or is it just black? Edit: Ah, I see the default is none which is black.

Comment: Do you set color code in value of input?

Answer (score 1):

I guess is can happen because of two reasons:

1. You forgot to set the data while you generate the page using your php code. You need something like:
    `<input type="color" id="theId" value="#<some php code to get the value>" />`
2. You missed the "#". "#220056" gives a color, but "220056" gives Black.

Hope it helps,
Regards

Answer (score -1):

Im sorry guys I made a mistake.
In my databse column I limited the characters to 6.
I forgot # is also a character so I had to do char(7)
Now it works!
Still thanks for your help and answers.